Error on OpportunityShare records
I have written an Apex Sharing class, I need to share the Opportunities to the users who has the Same role as Opportunity Owner in the Org, and this is not for the entire Org Only for few roles, the roles belong to YEF. and user need to add the Opportunity Team Members as well. I have written the code the opportunities were not shared, when I test the things in Anonymous window to debug I got the error: Insert Failed. First exception on row 1; first error: INSUFFICIENT _ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE _ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross -reference id:[].
Please Help me to Fix this error.
Code:
public class OpportunityShareYEF {
    public static void shareRecord(List<Id> opportunityIds) {
        List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Id, Name, Owner.UserRole.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Owner.UserRole.Name LIKE '%YEF%' AND Id IN :opportunityIds];
        List<OpportunityShare> oppShares = new List<OpportunityShare>();
        List<User> usersWithSameRole = [SELECT Id, userRole.Name, userRoleId FROM User WHERE userRole.Name LIKE '%YEF%'];
        for (Opportunity opp : oppList) {
            // List<User> usersWithSameRole =[SELECT Id FROM User WHERE UserRoleId = :opp.Owner.UserRoleId];
            if (opp.OwnerId != null) {
                System.debug('Processing Opportunity: ' + opp.Id + ', Owner Role: ' + opp.Owner.UserRole.Name);
                for (User user : usersWithSameRole) {
                    System.debug('Processing User: ' + user.Id + ', User Role: ' + user.UserRole.Name);
                    if (user.UserRoleId == opp.Owner.UserRoleId) {
                        System.debug('User Role Id' + user.UserRoleId);
                        System.debug('Owner Role Id' + opp.Owner.UserRoleId);
                        OpportunityShare oppShare = new OpportunityShare();
                        oppShare.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
                        oppShare.UserOrGroupId = user.Id;
                        oppShare.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
                        oppShare.RowCause = Schema.OpportunityShare.RowCause.Manual;
                        oppShares.add(oppShare);
                        System.debug('Opportunity Share created for Opportunity: ' + opp.Id + ' with User: ' + user.Id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        insert oppShares;
    }
}

Thanks

Be sure  to avoid sharing the record to the current Opportunity.OwnerId as that user already has an implicit share to the record

Here you can find really good explanation.

The error is throw when you try to insert/update something that logically cannot be inserted/updated.


Some examples:


You try to update a record that does not exist. Maybe the record was never there or it was deleted.


You try to update an object field that cannot be set explicitly. These fields can only be updated by the implicitly. e.g.: object owner, CreatedById, CreatedDate, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate. You cannot explicitly update these fields.


You are trying to give permission to someone but you yourself do not have permission for this.


If you are trying to share "Record X" with "User Y" and you yourself do not have access to "Record x", this error happens Or if the "User Y" already has access to it.

Are you sure you have access to opportunities that meet the criteria?
SELECT Id, Name, Owner.UserRole.Name 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE Owner.UserRole.Name LIKE '%YEF%' AND Id IN :opportunityIds

